# How can I force screen sharing with a plugin in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, screensharing

I don't know where to start looking for solution, so here it is.

I need to hide the firefox popup when my page wants to screenshare and force screensharing of screen 1:

[image: firefox screensharing popup]

I saw that i cannot do this in javascript, but I can do it via a plugin.

I have total control on the computers that need to have this feature, so there is no security issue for the user, and I can install the plugin if I want to.

I have played a bit with the "navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia" function, but I don't know where I can go from there.

If someone can help, that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just because you might be able to do this - and there's no "security issue" - doesn't mean it doesn't raise all kinds of ethical implications. Essentially it sounds like you want to spy on your users without them knowing. There's a possibility people here might have a problem trying to help you with that.

Comment: Hey, this concern is legitimate. However the user will chose to screenshare by himself. I cannot let him chose the screen he wants to share nor want to display any unwanted dialog box. The computers are owned by me and the user can just use the touchscreen and do nothing else with it. So, ethically i'm ok :)

Comment: Your question is about you wanting to __force__ screen share without users' __consent__. A user can't _choose_ to screen share if you remove their only means of denying the request.

Comment: The user consent to screenshare with a custom screen beforehand. I don't want them to select which screen to share, as they can do things I dont want to.